# Call from OSGI bundle Datasource

Tags: java, jsf, osgi, jboss7.x

Following this tutorial http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-osgiservice-cdi.html
I have managed to create a simple OSGI bundle and a client web application. I placed a managed bean into the web application client. The managed been calls a interface placed into the OSGI bundle. I successfully compile the code.
  Now the interesting part is can I place a data into the OSGI bundle which can make queries to the database. This is the code that I placed into the OSGI bundle:

```
package com.test;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

/** include default packages for Beans */
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
   // or import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
/** include package for SHA-256 encryption */
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
/** include SQL Packages */
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
   // or import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; 



@Remote
public interface SL_43Remote {

    @Resource(name="java:/Oracle")
    private DataSource ds;



}
```

Betbeans 7.1 shows error: "modifier private is not allowed" and "= expected".
Maybe I'm missing some libraries or maybe OSGI bundles don't allow source code for working  with databases.
  Any idea how to fix the problem?

Kind Regards.
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private fields are not allowed on interfaces in Java.

This problem has nothing to do with OSGi, just the fundamentals of Java.